# What is the logical process behind making geometry proofs?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

[Symbolab Medial Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2auG.png)

Attached is an image I made using symbolab. I know after the givens you would use $BE = CF$, and then triangle $BDE = \triangle CFD$ (insert postulate) followed up with a reflexive, but what else is there to do? I get really confused when it seems like there should be more content in the proof but it looks like every point and angle has been used already

Comment: In terms of "what else is there to do", I suggest you open an elementary geometry book, and read a few proofs.

Comment: @uniquesolution That's the point. My crappy saxon math textbook only has like 2 lessons on proofs, that aren't detailed and are all super simple ones. Where can I go online to learn proofs properly? Khan academy?

Comment: I would probably start with classic proofs from Euclid's Elements or Hilbert's Foundations of Geometry. Both works are available online.